# Can't understand the confusing behavior of Date time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```js
var localTime = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka'
});
var timeStamp = Number(new Date(localTime));

console.log(new Date(timeStamp))
```

When my computer's time is the local time it prints the UTC time but when I set my computer's time to UTC time it prints the local time! Shouldn't it always print my local time?

For an example when my computer's time is 19:46:46 it prints 2020-05-19T13:46:46.000Z (my timezone is UTC+6). When I change my computer's time to 13:46:46 it prints 2020-05-19T19:46:46.000Z.

[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c5hJEfihl-noyTEyZR3-IqBcOzolXcM-) is the screenshots of my computer's time.

Comment: Can you provide some concrete numbers here, instead of this vague abstract explanation?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can't reliably parse the string from `toLocaleString` using `new Date`. And if it *does* get parsed, you have no idea whehter it was parsed as UTC or local time.

Comment: "when I set it to UTC time" could mean the JavaScript, or your computer's time zone, or your computer's actual time. You need to be much clearer.

Comment: This feels a lot like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by doing the above?

Comment: @Quentin "when I set it to UTC time" what I meant by that is actually changing my computers time

Comment: Please post 1) the time your computer is set to, 2) the actual time, 3) what this code gives you, for both your stated scenarios.

Comment: And (4) the time zone your computer is set to

Comment: I have edited my post mentioning my timezone

Comment: Your computer's timezone remains set to +6 throughout, and you just change its time?

Comment: It would also help if you'd show the output of `localTime`…

Comment: I changed the timezone to utc coordinated universal time and then reset it to UTC+6

Comment: Well, now I'm confused what exactly your computer's set to when you get that weird result…

Comment: I am sharing 2 screen shots here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c5hJEfihl-noyTEyZR3-IqBcOzolXcM-

Answer (score 0):

It's not confusing. Its *always* local time of the machine *where it's running*. `toLocaleString()` doesn't convert between timezones. The second parameter changes how the date is represented in that zone (language, format). The date and time are the same.

A good solution could be to always use UTC and convert it from there whenever you need to display it as local time. That way you could control what local time is.

`Date.UTC()` will let you create an UTC date, or you can use the methods `date.getUTCxxx()`.